# How to import things in Python stub files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, packaging, type-hinting

I'm annotating types for the `aiojira` library using stub files. `aiojira` library follows the same structure as `jira` library. `jira` library contains `resilientsession` module, so I think I should create `resilientsession.pyi` file and import it in `__init__.pyi`. I did this, but when write:

```py
import aiojira.resilientsession
```

PyCharm complains, `mypy` complains:

```
kgjirawebhook/__init__.py:7: error: Cannot find module named 'aiojira.resilientsession'
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be because aiojira is not installed in your current environment. Relative import should fix this problem.

Try:

```
from . import resilientsession
```